# is it possible to use opentok/tokbox in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a video chat application for android mobiles so I decided to use opentok for it.Now I have questions and some apprehensions.a)

Is it possible to use opentok for android phones?If yes then is it using the adobe AIR?Any Help in this regard will be Thankful!It will be great if you give me some tutorial for Developing in adobe AIR Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago, you could watch a stream, but you couldn't publish one as Flash for Android does not have access to the camera.

However, recently OpenTok has recently tried to rectify this:
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-gets-its-first-mobile-features-2/